# jquery xml issue when using google chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, json

When I'm using FF and IE I can see all images in the [gallery](http://damacanapaleti.gen.tr/urunler/). But when i use Google Chrome I can't see any images. I suppose this problem origanate for jquery and xml file. There is my [config.xml](http://www.damacanapaleti.gen.tr/urunler/config.xml) what is the problem and how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @DanBarzilay You can see on web source.

Comment: it would be easier for us if you copied it to here..

Comment: Thats not my codes. It have 5-6 javascript files :). If it is important I can paste here all.

Comment: just the one that reads the xml and showing the images...

Answer (score 0):

First, as a sanity check:  no, there is nothing obviously wrong with your XML configuration file.

Inspecting the page as served in Chrome and Safari shows (a) that your problem is reproducible (hurrah!) and (b) that in Chrome, the first `img` element in the gallery carries an attribute reading

```
style="width: 0px; height: 0px; opacity: 0.6;"
```

I see that the second `img` doesn't have the `opacity` setting, but it does have the `width` and `height` set to 0px.

Find the code that's setting height and width for the images; it seems likely to be the culprit.

Comment: Here is my css file: http://ideone.com/D6j6E What i need to do. I can't see any width parameter that is 0px; ??

Comment: The width and height settings are not coming from your external CSS file; they are in a `style` attribute on the `img` element.  Use View / Developer / Developer Tools to browse the HTML as the browser is seeing it.

Comment: @cm I can't find thats really. I'm using this script: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/24/multimedia-gallery/

Comment: It's puzzling.  The width and height of items in the gallery appear to be set in jquery.multimediagallery.js based on simple arithmetic with the image's intrinsic height and width; no obvious flaws there.  And the gallery works fine in Chrome on the tympanus.net site.  Whatever the problem is, it affects both the gallery view and the 'center preview' view on your site.  Server configuration issue? If you have an older version of the package, get the current version.  If you have mucked with it, undo your changes.  Other than that I have no idea where to go next.